# Webgl passing color variables to shaders

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have been trying to **pass a color variable (vColor) from JavaScript to my shaders.** I have tried lots of different things in the JavaScript, but have not been able to pass the variable.

I sort of understand how the vPosition variable in this code was passed. I tried doing the same thing for vColor, but got errors like

*Error: WebGL: enableVertexAttribArray: -1 is not a valid `index`. This value probably comes from a getAttribLocation() call, where this return value -1 means that the passed name didn't correspond to an active attribute in the specified program.*

**Will someone please help me understand this?**

Here are the shaders

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;
void main()
{
    fColor=vColor;
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 vColor;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
</script>
```

And here is the JavaScript

```
"use strict";
var gl;
var points;
window.onload = function init()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    // Four Vertices

    var vertices = [
      -0.5, -0.5,
      -0.5,  0.5,
      0.5, 0.5,
      0.5, -0.5
    ];


    //
    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    render();
};


function render() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your shader, you're using *vColor* both as an *attribute name* and as a *uniform name*. This is probably what caused confusion in the browser. It's better to assume uniforms, attributes, and varyings form a single name space, and assign different names for uniforms and attributes. I also see a possible mistake:

```
uniform vec4 vColor;
```

Did you mean this to be a *varying*?

```
varying vec4 fColor;

....

gl_FragColor = fColor;
```